# SoundCloud player widget ignores show_artwork setting

Tags: soundcloud

The SoundCloud Player Widget always shows the artwork, even if I set `show_artwork=false`.  Are there plans to support this parameter?  If this parameter is no longer supported, it should be removed from the widget docs at

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking at the old flash player or the new (where new = since 2011) HTML5 player?

Here's a player with artwork turned off:

https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/33427584&show_artwork=false

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Turns out that the `visual` property is overriding `show_artwork`.  The default HTML generated by the SoundCloud website has `visual=true`.

A related issue is that `visual` isn't documented on the SoundCloud Player Widget page.